# How can I install PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, php

How can I replace PHP 5.3 with PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04? I searched with Google and failed to find a repository.

Comment: There is not a stable php 5.5 yet.

Comment: [How to setup latest version of PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) with 3 simple bash commands

Answer (score 14):

You can use my PPA with PHP 5.5: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

Comment: Is it stable now?

Comment: Yes, there are still couple of missing extensions which I will provide in due time, and it also needs newer Apache 2.4 (also included), but I would say that the repository is in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find PPA for 5.5 (and rightly so) so I think either you wait or build it yourself.
Instruction to build yourself are found [here](http://www.brandonsavage.net/compiling-php-5-5-from-scratch/)
However, if you like, few PPAs for PHP 5.4 exists if that can be compromise.

Checkout these:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa

****EDIT****

The ppa:ondrej/php5 now contains PHP 5.5. PHP 5.4 has been moved to ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable. So you have what you want!

Comment: JFTR The ppa:ondrej/php5 now contains PHP 5.5.  PHP 5.4 has been moved to ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable.